# MASM32 Assembling error - C:\masm32\bin\ml.exe is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: assembly, masm32

Wanting to learn some Assembly programming, I installed the [MASM32 SDK](http://www.masm32.com/download.htm). After that, I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCjbwLeLNfs). So, after creating my first asm file, I navigated to its folder through the command prompt, then typed:

```
\masm32\bin\ml /c /Zd /coff [name of my asm file]
```

just as the guy does at 2:40 in the video.

At this point, instead of getting the successful Assembling message, a window pops up, telling me that:

```
C:\masm32\bin\ml.exe is not a valid Win32 application
```

Why am I getting this? How can I solve?

My OS is 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: This may be a corrupted installation, try downloading it again from a different mirror. `ml.exe` is a PE32 application, it is supported on Windows 7 (and later). I've run it a lot of times without any problem.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Weird stuff. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Not sure, the point of QA is to help not only you but also future readers. If you can edit it with the offending mirror and self-answer maybe it will be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by reinstalling the MASM32 SDK (same install.exe). To uninstall, simply delete the /masm32 folder. Solution suggested by Margaret Bloom.

Comment: what was the offending mirror and from what mirror did you get your new installation?

Answer (score 0):

Please try it in Windows XP Mode (if you have Windows 7 Professional edition or above)!
Windows XP Mode provides 32-bit virtual OS inside Windows 7 64-bit and can be downloaded and installed for users with Professional or above Windows 7 editions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just have a standard Home Premium edition.

Comment: 64-bit Windows doesn't have any problem running 32-bit apps